# Adding custom font to _typography.less parse error

Tags: magento2, css, less, fonts

I try to add some custom fonts to my theme, so I created file `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/_typography.less` and added the code inside of it:

```
.lib-font-face (
  @family-name:'OpenSans Condensed Light',
  @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/OpenSans-CondLight.ttf',
  @font-weight: 300,
  @font-style: normal
)
```

When I use grunt to compile less files, I get a parse error:

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input in pub/static/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/[lang]/css/source/_typography.less on line 1, column 16:
>> 1 .lib-font-face (
>> 2   @family-name:'OpenSans Condensed Light',
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I forgot to use ; at the end of the sentence - when I added ; - it worked.

Comment: You haven't forget ;. It is missing in "documentation" =)

Comment: I am using `.lib-font-face(
    @family-name:'custom-icon',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/custom-icon',
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal
)` and it is throwing similar exception. How do I correct it wrt your answer?

Comment: Add ; in the end. For example:

.lib-font-face (

);

Answer (score 0):

Please use below format:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSans-Regular';
    src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.eot');
    src: url('@{baseDir}fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('@{baseDir}fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts@{baseDir}fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. The browser tries to load the font, but the font is not placed in /pub/static anywhere